# wordpress 5.9 generates big ttfb and slows the website

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a strange situation : I updated a website to Wordpress 5.9 and suddenly the page loading time increased from 1-2 seconds to 15+ seconds. Looking over the network tab i see that the TTFB is increased to 11+ seconds.

I created a test domain  and installed WordPress 5.8.3. Added the same theme with no content - just the "hello world" post. The loading speed is 0.6 seconds . If i update to 5.9 the loading time becomes 11+seconds.

Here are 2 screen captures from query monitor
5.8 -0.6 seconds
[image]

5.9 -11.6 sec
[image]

The server details are

Version 7.4.27

SAPI    fpm-fcgi

max_execution_time  600

memory_limit    512M

upload_max_filesize 128M

post_max_size   128M

Server Version  5.5.5-10.3.32-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.20.04.1

Extension   mysqli

Client Version  70427 (7.4.27)

I start disabling portions of  code and i think i can tie the big loading times to get_header and wp_head() functions but i could not pinpoint the problem. I also disabled all the hooks and filters but with no luck.

I checked the database queries and the load is not coming from there - you can see from screen captures also.

I disabled Gutenberg styles on front end

I read the release log for 5.9 but i did not saw something that could affect the website.

Any advice will be appreciated since i'm running out of ideas.